# Php sql echo only one row if field duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Say i have a table called managers with 3 fields and i have 10 rows.

```
id        AgeGroup    name
1         a           1
2         a           2
3         a           3
4         b           4
5         b           5
6         c           6
7         d           7
8         d           8
9         d           9
10        e           10
```

code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$query = "SELECT * FROM managers ORDER BY AgeGroup ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());    

echo'<ul>';
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo'<li>'.$row['AgeGroup'].'</li>';
    } 
} 
echo'</ul>';
```

I want to be able to echo the agegroup field but have no repeats.
Ie the output would be :

```
a
b 
c 
d 
e
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) clause in your query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM managers GROUP BY AgeGroup  ORDER BY AgeGroup ASC";
```

Answer (score 2):

Several options are possible:

```
SELECT * FROM managers GROUP BY AgeGroup ORDER BY AgeGroup ASC
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT AgeGroup FROM managers ORDER BY AgeGroup ASC
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Does an SQL-based solution help? Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT AgeGroup FROM managers ORDER BY AgeGroup ASC
```

This way you don't need anything in the PHP code to change.

Comment: Argh, I can't comment on others' posts yet :-) Shakti Singh, Patrick B.: `select * ... group by AgeGroup` is not valid SQL, although MySQL will accept it. VikasNaranje: `select AgeGroup ... group by AgeGroup` is effectively the same as `select distinct AgeGroup`, but less readable.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS

```
SELECT AgeGroup FROM managers GROUP BY AgeGroup ORDER BY AgeGroup ASC
```